# inversed use of like withquery builder

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

All is in the title.

```
    $qb->expr()->like('a.lieu', ':advertLieu');
->setParameter('advertLieu', $postedAdvert->getVille()->getName()."%")
```

This will check if in the ***a.lieu*** entry there is a substring starting with the ***advertLieu*** parameter.

I want the inverse , like this :

```
$qb->expr()->like(':advertLieu', '%a.lieu%',);
    ->setParameter('advertLieu', $postedAdvert->getVille()->getName())
```

So, check if ma database entry ***a.lieu*** is contained in the parameter ***advertLieu***

I found this : [MySQL: What is a reverse version of LIKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472063/mysql-what-is-a-reverse-version-of-like) but How can i implement this in my query builder ?

> Update

I have a similar question : 
If i have a collection of entity in my database and want to check if my parameter exist in this array like :  `$qb->expr()->in('u.ids', $id)`

I mean check if u.ids contain $id. Is it possible ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$qb->expr()
    ->like(
        ':advertLieu', 
        $qb->expr()
            ->concat(
                $qb->expr()->literal('%'), 
                $qb->expr()->concat('a.lieu', $qb->expr()->literal('%'))
            )
     );
->setParameter('advertLieu', $postedAdvert->getVille()->getName())
```

For your update I would suggest you do this:

```
$qb->expr()->in('u.id', ':ids');
->setParameter('ids', $id)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot . Maybe can you answer to my update. I have a similar case but i don't know how to implement it

Comment: Thanks for reply , for the second question, i want the inverse use. Check if the array collection ( who is in database) contain the parameter $id. In you case, it look like  i'll pass the array in parameter and not the unique id.

Comment: NVM, i found the solution , we can use like on serialized object [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709699/symfony2-doctrine2-display-items-by-category-with-query)

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding. Glad you found the solution.