# Doctrine Querying many to many [Semantical Error]

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

At present I having following 3 tables.

articles_categories

```
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| article_id  | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| category_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

category

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

article

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In Category Entity

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="categories")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"createdAt" = "DESC"})
     */
    protected $articles;
```

In Article Entity

```
/**
     * All categories this article belongs to.
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="articles", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="articles_categories")
     */
    protected $categories;
```

Most of queries works fine. But I want to get articles that belongs to a category. Or that have a specific category or Want to filter Articles based on Category.

For that I wrote following query.

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('c');
        $qb->select('1')
            ->from('articles_categories', 'a_c')
            ->leftJoin('\\Chip\\Entity\\Article', 'a', 'WITH', 'a.id = a_c.article_id')
            ->leftJoin('\\Chip\\Entity\\Category', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.id = a_c.category_id')
        ;

        $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

But it throws following error.

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 14 near 'articles_categories': Error: Class 'articles_categories' is not defined.
500 Internal Server Error - QueryException
1 linked Exception: QueryException »
```

Any help or hints or any better ways to write queries would be great.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The `articles_categories` is not a Doctrine mapped class and it don't is an ORM Class. For your needed you don't need to specify the relation table between the entity but only the existing relation between them.

Comment: check this answer for some example http://stackoverflow.com/a/19710312/2270041

Comment: @Matteo Thank you very much. You solved the issue.

Comment: hi @bharatesh you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use table names in your query builder, instead you should use class names.

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('c');
$qb->select('c', 'a')
   ->from('Chip\Entity\Category', 'c') // this line is not necessary when performing this query in your category repository
   ->leftJoin('c.articles, a')
   ->where('c.id = 1');
$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Yes. thank you for hint. I think solution is in the link     stackoverflow.com/a/19710312/2270041